# Android DatePickerDialog creates random wrong month

Tags: java, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog, java.util.calendar

When I implement a DatePickerDialog it display the correct date but when I click OK to set the date in an EditText I get a date String with incorrect month, which seems to be random each time I try

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String newDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
        Log.e(TAG,"date: "+newDate);
        mTextSetDate.setText(newDate);
    }
};
```

And to display the DatePickerDialog, I have this function

```
private void showDatePicker(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, Calendar cal){
new DatePickerDialog(AddNewRecordActivity.this,listener,
        cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

}

and here's the log output

```
09-26 08:20:13.511 4240-4240/tz.co.neelansoft.personalaccountant E/AddNewRecordActivity: date: 26-18-2018
```

I included some screenshot of [datepickerdialog](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A8FpbwJ28CP8jc5lvCbI18qWP6HDyw8J) and [date string](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j3rtfsklLQ6mkxc95bZC6mOchgNOX-En)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.